# хранение токенов и другой персональной информации

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuex, jwt

Товарищи доброго времени суток. Хочу сделать авторизацию на сайте:

**На сервере:**

```
//... тут коннект в базу проверяем соединение по логину и паролю

let token = jwt.sign({ id: ..from DataBase}, config.jwtpass, { expiresIn: 86400 });

res.status(200).send({
  token: token,
  user: {
    uid: ..from DataBase,
    name: ..from DataBase,
    is_admin: ..from DataBase
  }
})
```

**На клиенте:**

```
// ... далее записываю в store, localstorage ..
localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(response.data.user))
localStorage.setItem('token',JSON.stringify(response.data.token))
$axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = response.data.token
```

На клиенте использую vuex. Прочитал кучу информации где говорится что не стоит хранить в localstorage токены и др информацию(мне например на клиенте нужно свойство is_admin). Действительно зашел в ls, поменял flag is_admin и прошел по путям админа.. Подскажите как правильнее сделать?

Comment: is_admin не нужно, а токен собственно больше негде хранить

Comment: Ну ещё можно в куке хранить, конечно.

Comment: @AlexeyTen а где хранить свойство is_admin ?

Comment: А зачем его хранить?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, я думал через meta свойства в роутах определять(beforeEach) кто заходит(если admin то открывать соответствующий контент иначе нет)..

Comment: Никаких is_admin на клиенте, все проверки админа делать строго на сервере и только

Comment: @andreymal, я вас понял. Но как тогда на клиенте узнать что зашел админ?

Comment: Ну можно оставить is_admin для одной-единственной вещи - отобразить ссылку на админку. А вот секретный контент, связанный с админкой, должен подгружаться с сервера только после клика по такой ссылке и после всех проверок на сервере. Если подгрузить какой-то админский контент заранее без проверок, пользователь найдёт способ его вытащить даже если он скрыт (он всё-таки целиком контролирует свой браузер)

Comment: @andreymal, я это и имел ввиду. Вопрос состоял именно нормальная ли это практика хранить токен и такую информацию в localstorage

Comment: Ну ничего лучше пока не придумали

Answer (score -1):

Использовать cookies для AAA-задач. Изучите этот материал - https://scotch.io/bar-talk/why-jwts-suck-as-session-tokens и другие подобные для понимания почему нужно делать именно так.